# Google Sheets - Track and Log highest and lowest value of other (dynamic) cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a sheet for paper trading Stocks and Crypto. The values in A are refreshed every 5 minutes. In B, I have the current Date and Time.  At the moment, I have a workaround that sends a mail if a value meets a certain criteria. But it is not ideal. Another workaround would be to log every API request of a value as historical. But that would take every 5 minutes 2000 rows.  I would like to log the values of a couple specified rows (trades). The Highest Value and Lowest value and the Timestamp of the logged value. Is there a way? I included a picture of how I would see it. I tried Google and the search within Stack Overflow without any result. The timestamp is a Bonus, the Log is the most important. I think it could be done within the App Script. But not sure.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `the values in A are refreshed every 5min , in B i have the current date and Time.` and the image. Can I ask you about the detail of it? About `the values in A are refreshed every 5min`, the values are put by the time-driven trigger using Google Apps Script? And about `At the moment i have a workaround that sends a mail if a value meets a certain criteria. But its not ideal. A other workaround would be to log every Api request of a value as historical.`, can you provide these script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Question on Freelacer.com . This is the code i was looking for : Code added as picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzzww.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).